# Pear XML Serializer and Attributes

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, pear

is there a way, to "tell" the PEAR XML_Serializer, which properties it should serialize as attribute and which as sub element?

For example:

```
class User {
  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $address;
}
```

Should be serialized like this:

```
<User id="0">
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <address></address>
</User>
```

I thought about using the "XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_SCALAR_AS_ATTRIBUTES" Option, but unfortunately, I need some scalars as attribute and some as sub element.

Is there a way to tell the XML_Serializer how he should serialize the properties of the source class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done some code review and got the solution:

```
$serializer->setOption(
  XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_SCALAR_AS_ATTRIBUTES => array(
    "User" => array("id")
  )
);
```

Does the trick ... everything will be serialized as XML-Element but the "id" property of the User Element will be serialized as Attribute